# Is this the correct way for finding the margin of error of two samples?

Tags: statistics

[image]

What I have for (b) is

1.96(sqrt(207.11/8.00 + 200.45/6.10)) = 15.023

Something seems off. Not sure about the second part.

Best will surely be upvoted.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you have computed a normal confidence interval, which would be correct if the standard deviations given were for the _populations_ instead of the _samples._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Minitab output for a Welch (separate variances) 95% t confidence
interval $(3.78, 9.54):$

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample   N    Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       50  207.11   8.00      1.1
2       45  200.45   6.10     0.91

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  6.66
95% CI for difference:  (3.78, 9.54)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): T-Value = 4.59  P-Value = 0.000  DF = 90
```

Notice that the CI does not contain 0, so it seems men plan to spend
significantly more than women. The point estimate of the difference is $6.66.

Perhaps you are supposed to do a pooled confidence interval. Minitab's confidence
interval of this type is: $(3.74, 9.58).$  This procedure assumes that the
*population* variances for men an women are the same and uses the pooled
estimate $S_p = 7.1642$ of the population standard deviation.

The Welch procedure is preferred by many practicing statisticians, but
the the pooled procedure is still presented in many textbooks (possibly
because it is a little easier to compute for homework and exams).

You should look in your text or notes to find the formulas for getting
these confidence intervals, then do the appropriate computation and see
that it matches the Minitab output.

Comment: Thanks. It tells me the margin of error is t*(standard error) or z*(standard error)

Comment: Or rather, t-critical x (standard error) and z-critical x (standard error)

Comment: Looking at the formula is might be: 1.96( (6.10)/50 + (8.00)/45 )

Comment: Because population standard deviations are unknown and estimated from the samples, you should use the t procedures. However, with samples as large as 50 and 45, there will not be much difference in the numerical answers.

Comment: So to three decimal places that is = 0.588, does all that look correct?

Comment: I know the z-critical for 95% would be 1.96, but unsure about what t-critical means as far as a score goes.

Comment: Thank you. It appears subbing in 1.987 would give me the same answer.

Comment: With df=90 as in the Welch interval you would use 1.987 instead of 1.96. I think the correct computation is $1.987\sqrt{8.00^2/50 + 6.10^2/45}=2.88.$ Also half the width of the Welch interval is $(9.54-3.76)/2 =2.89,$ which is the same except for rounding.

Comment: Thank you. Would you know how to solve (c)?